# How to disable image reloading in recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

In my recyclerview, if I scroll up/down images are reloaded again. it spoils user experience.

I know its default behavior of recyclerview. But I want to implement same like Whatsapp. They do not reload image if already loaded.  Anyone suggest to me.

**My Glide library code:**

```
   BitmapTypeRequest glideRequestmgr = Glide.with(context).load(getGlideURL(path, context)).asBitmap();

        glideRequestmgr.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .dontTransform()
                .dontAnimate()
                .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(Bitmap arg0, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> arg1) {
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(arg0);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I fixed that issue by put the recyclerview inside NestedScrollView

Step 1:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Step 2:

```
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Very interesting solution, may I know how this works? It worked for me as well. But curios to know how.

Comment: Most likely this would result in an OutOfMemeory error.

Comment: @SukithaUdugamasooriya yes, I agree. It's possible for OutOfMemory error. But in my case I have less data.   If you found any good solution post your answer to help others.

Comment: Although I am skeptical about the issue @SukithaUdugamasooriya mentioned, I had to use it without having any other option. But how is it even working? It works for me but I get a blank view for a second before loading recyclerview. Please comment if there are any better ways.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
GlideApp.with(context)
                    .asBitmap()
                    .load(pathToLoad)
                    .error(R.drawable.ob_glide_app_img_loader)
                    .listener(requestListener)
                    .into(simpleTarget)
```

Comment: good catch. I am using old version. thanks for suggestion I will try

Comment: also add .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).

Answer (score 0):

Use RecyclerView's property,

```
recyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
```